# Storing data in an array vs SQLite in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sqlite

I am working on an app where I need to retrieve (readonly) a few thousand items that are currently stored in an SQLite database. Since I pull and put everything into an array in Swift, I wonder if it'd be a good idea to put everything in an array from the start?

What would be some performance difference between array storage vs database storage and would one be better over the other?

Comment: as I know in every platform, it will use lazy loading, or you can use paging and limiting the output, so you not overload the RAM. 

My friend tells me, he had ~10,000 rows, load it all, and take 5 minutes in linux system

Comment: Core Data can mitigate these concerns a lot.  However, there is a big learning curve.  Once you get comfortable with Core Data it starts to feel a lot more natural than writing SQL. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Performance.html